# Adjust shrinkage penalty for random smooths

Tags: r, gam, random-effects

The function `gam::gam()` allows you to adjust the shrinkage parameter for a random effect as such:

```
fit = gam::gam(y ~ 1 + random(fac, df=5))
```

Is there a similar way to adjust the shrinkage parameter for random effects in `mgcv`? I'm not interested in setting the penalty to a fixed value by using `sp`. Instead, I wish to adjust the prior shrinkage before fitting, similar to how `k` works. I can set `gamma` to a value >1, but that will affect all smooths in the model. I can set `min.sp`, but that does not work with `method='fREML'` for `bam()` (I have a lot of smoothing parameters). Are there any additional options for `gam()`, `gamm()`, or `bam()`?